# Why jet engines can differ in shape?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, aircraft-performance, aircraft-systems

I have seen the shape of the A320s engine and for example the B737 engine, its different, I want to know why its different? is it just for designing?

Comment: The reason for it is because the 737 has a very unique shape and that shape is because it needs more ground clearance.